# Can we use jQueryUI and KendoUI at same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I have php app where jQueryUI library version 1.8.4. is already implemented with jquery library version 1.4.2. But as per new requirements I need to implement some modules in kendo UI library. So I installed stable version of kendoUI and integrated with my code base but it was giving me some issues so I updated my jquery version to latest stable version. Since then I am having jquery object conflicts. So I think problem is related with jqueryUI.

So can we use both jQueryUI and KendoUI libraries at same time in same page?

I am getting error like this - $.sub is not a function. kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource is not a constructor

Please anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should upgrade to the latest version of everything.

Comment: But can we use both kendoUI and jqueryUI libraries at same page?

Comment: You can. What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting error like this -
$.sub is not a function.

kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource is not a constructor

Comment: Are you sure it is jQuery UI related and not only breaking changes from your Kendo update?

Answer (score 2):

@All,

Thanks for your help guys. My issues gets resolved. Now I have point my js to udpated CDN server jquery js, jqueryUI js and kendoUI js. By doing this I got conflicts like .live is not working and all but I have resolved them by using their alternatives.
Thanks once again.

Comment: I had the same problem. Upgrading to the latest jQuery and jQuery.UI solved the problem of jQuery.UI and kendo.ui not working on the same page.

Comment: Kendo UI has dependency on Jquery. So when you add kendo ui in package.json, you get jquery as well and jquery ui dist has to be added explicitly. How did you make jquery ui use kendo.jquery? In my case, $ variable is not getting initialized.

Answer (score -1):

Kendo depends on jQuery! Therefore, yes you can have both of them at the same page. Different versions of Kendo depends on different versions of jQuery.

Latest Kendo (such as 2013.1.319) works with jQuery 1.9. Upgrading your jQuery from 1.8.4 to 1.9 is quite fun (follow http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/). If you are using some 3rd party js plugins/libs what are based on 1.8.4 in your project you might need to upgrade them  too.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. jQuery != jQuery UI

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question !